# GWT Widget not properly set in the DOM

Tags: gwt, dom, printing

I would like to print a GWT widget which extends Composite. This widget is composed of a grid whose cells are built with a ListDataProvider. When the user clic on a button print, the widget to print is built. Once this is done, I launch the print:

```
    Element element = widgetToPrint.getElement();
    String content = element.getInnerHTML();
    print(content);


    public static native boolean print(String content)
    /*-{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Printing', '');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Test</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/ToPrintWidget.css" type="text/css" media="all"/></head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(content);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    return true;
    }-*/;
```

So, here is my problem:

The window which is opened by this method contains the core of the widget (built by the UI Binder), but some children are missing...

If I look inside the ListDataProvider and its related FlowPanel, the data are consistent, i.e. I've got several item in my list and in the flowPanel.

Consequently, it should be visible on the printing window...
I thought that maybe the problem was related to the method used to print the widget, so I also tried to add this widget into a dialogbox just before launching the print, to see if the widget was properly built... and it was.

So my widget displays well on a dialogbox, but if I try to give its innerHTML to the print method, by using getElement(), some widgets are missing... I've the feeling that the widgets which should have been built when the ListDataProvider changes are not properly set in the DOM... Somehow it works when I add the widget to a regular component, but it doesn't work when I have to give directly its innerHTML...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Widgets are not just the sum of their elements, and DOM elements are not just the string that they are serialized to. Widgets are the element, and all events sunk to the dom to listen for any changes or interactions by the user. Elements then have callback functions or handlers they invoke when the user interacts with them.

By serializing the element (i.e. invoking `getInnerHTML()`), you are only reading out the structure of the dom, not the callbacks, and additionally not the styles set by CSS. This probably shouldn't be expected to work correctly, and as your experience is demonstrating, it doesn't.

As this is just a print window you are trying to create, event handling is probably not a concern. You just want the ability to see, but not interact with, the content that would be in that set of widgets. Styles are probably the main problem here then (though your question doesn't specify 'some children are missing' doesn't tell us what is missing, or give us any more clues as to why...) - you are adding one stylesheet in your JSNI code, but CellTable (which I assume you are using since you reference ListDataProvider) needs additional CssResource instances to appear correctly. I'm not sure how you can hijack those to draw in a new window.

Are you only using this to print content, not to let the user directly interact with the data? If so, consider another approach - use a SafeHtmlBuilder to create a giant, properly escaped string of content to draw in the new window.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. You're right about the window, its purpose is to be printed, no interaction with the user is expected. I'm going to try with the SafeHtmlBuilder, as you suggested, but if it also gives a string, I wonder why this one may contain the missing children ? Otherwise, about your questions on my topic: the missing children are those related to the CellTable. When I have a look on element, I can see its CellList which is not empty. Consequently, I assume that the widget is properly built, and actualy it displays well on the dialogBox...not on the print window

Comment: I 've search a bit, but I do not see how I can use a SafeHTMLBuilder to get a string from a widget... Could you give me the  basic Idea, please ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the SafeHtmlBuilder was intended to be a replacement to building a widget, since a widget really isn't built to operate the way you are asking it to. Thomas Broyer's suggestion of cloning all of the nodes of the widget gets close, but if using CellGrid/DataTable/etc or any other widget that relies on CssResources to behave, you are still going to miss out on those styles, which get added as the widget is constructed, and more importantly in your case, to the *wrong window*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to grab the *outer HTML* rather than the *inner* one.

GWT unfortunately has no `getOuterHTML`, but it's relatively easy to *emulate*.

- If your widget is the only child within an element, then simply get the inner HTML of the parent element (`w.getElement().getParentElement().getInnerHTML()`)
- Otherwise, clone your widget's node add it to a newly created parent element, from which you'll be able to get the inner HTML:

  ```java
  DivElement temp = Document.get().createDivElement();
  temp.appendChild(w.getElement().cloneNode(true));
  return temp.getInnerHTML();
  ```

Comment: Hello. If I follow you, you're suggesting to write: String content = data.getString(); instead of String content = data.getInnerHTML(); ? I just tried it, it doesn't work either... But thx anyway

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I was on mobile. See updated answer. As the javadoc says, `toString()` should only be used for debugging.

Comment: No problem. I've put my widget to print inside a flowpanel which doesn't contain anything else. Then I get the outerHTML as you suggested. It looks like: 
    
    PrintWidget printWidget = new PrintWidget();
    printer.add(printWidget);
    printWidget.update();
    Element element = printWidget.getElement().getParentElement();
    String content = element.getInnerHTML();
    Window.alert(content);
    print(content);

There is still nothing in the String content, and when I inspect the widget with firebug, it is empty...

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = element.toString();
```

This will include all hierarchy elements in the node.

Just a reminder, all the GWT handlers will not work, and you have to sink all the events using DOM.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. I just tried it... but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @user1873805 did you initialize all the widget content in the constructor? Dont put the code in onLoad method.

Comment: All widgets are built by the constructor, there is nothing in onLoad(). Moreover, the widget doesn't listen to any events, ie once the widget is built, he won't change.

Comment: @user1873805 That's weird. I tried using the same thing as you did in GWT and it worked fine. `getInnerHTML` will not work properly for sure but `toString` worked for me.

Comment: @user1873805 Try to use an alert box or print somewhere to try if `toString` can print the code for your missing widget. If not, the problem is then for widget initialization then.

Comment: I've done it, the String content doesn't contain any labels related to my missing widgets... So, this is indeed a problem of widget initialization. However, when I display the widget in a dialogBox, the missing widgets appear well. I guess that when the widget is added somewhere and shown, then maybe, it wakes up the render method which ends the refresh... However, I also tried to launch the print after showing the dialogbox, just to know if showing the widgets was the key, but it doesn't work better...

Comment: @user1873805 Are you sure all the widgets inside does not contain `onLoad` method? Because that is the main rendering function that is get called after showing...

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The widget is relatively simple, it is a grid of widgets, the grid has no onLoad, and the lines have no onLoad. The cells are built automatically when the listDataProvider changes, so I cann't tell about that one...which is just the one which doesn't work... But I do not see how to change that...

Comment: @user1873805 You can load the widget in your main program first, and set visible to false, then do toString and show the new window

Comment: I've did as you suggested: the widget is added from the beginning at the main windwow, but it is not visible. When I clic on print, I make it visible, I update it (which creates new lines in the widget) and then I use the toString to print it. It doesn't work either...

Comment: @user1873805 The only explanation is the rows are not within the hierarchy of the widget. You have to go over the HTML, and find where the rows are, use JS `document.findElementsByClass` to find the list of them, and add them to the window. I never used `CellList` in GWT but I build my own table grid and rows(which is not hard) and I can ensure all widgets inside the same hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for your answers, it helped me to work out this problem.
I've almost solve the problem:

First, I do not use ListDataProvider anymore, because it wasn't clear for me when and how the view was refreshed. Instead I add my widgets by hand, which makes sense since, they are not going to move anyway.

Then, I define the style of my widgets using a common CSS stylesheet. However, in order to do it, I can't rely on CssResource, which was the way I was used to do it with GWT. I think that this comes from the JS method which gets lost by this kind of styles... Instead, I have to specify everything in a static CSS stylesheet, and to give it to the JS.

It works perfectly well, ie, I have my widgets, with thei styles, and I can print it.

But...
The color of some widgets depends on the color of the object that they represent. Consequently, I cannot write a generic CSS stylesheet... And as I said, I can't add a style using CssResource... Do you have any ideas on the way to handle that ?

To make sure I'm clear on the way I'm adding styles, here is an example:

```
    Label l = new Label("Here is a cell in my grid to be printed");
    l.addStyleName("PrintLineCell-kind_1");
```

With, in a public CSS stylesheet:

```
    .PrintLineCell-kind_1{
        background-color: red;
    }
```

I hope there is a better way than to write 300 styles to cover 300 different colors...

Comment: Something like `label.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red")` might work for your color issue.

Comment: YES !! YES !! YES !! Thank you so much ! It might not be the best way, but it works perfectly, and that is all I'm asking for ! Thank you again for the help.